# Trying to make sense of, and rewrite, nested if/else

Tags: php

I inherited a script that contains a lot of PHP shorthand. I generally dislike PHP shorthand because of readability, and don't have a lot of experience with it outside of an occasional simple ternary.

I came across a block structured like this. The block is much larger, but this is the gist of it...

```php
if ($foo)
    $bar = true;
else
    if ($bar)
    $baz = true;
else
    $barbaz = true;
```

Would this be the proper way to rewrite it, so it's more readable?

```php
if ($foo) {
    $bar = true;
} else {
    if ($bar) {
        $baz = true;
    }
} else {
    $barbaz = true;
}
```

#### EDIT

Here's another example

```php
if ($foo)
    $bar = true;
else
    if ($bar)
    $baz = true;
else
    if ($barbaz)
    $something = true;
else
    $barbaz = true;
```

When I turned the `else if` into `elseif` the script broke.

Comment: `elseif` is your friend :)

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah, that broke the script lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
$foo = 2;
$bar = 3;
if ($foo > $bar) {
    $baz = 'Greater';
} elseif ($foo === $bar) {
    $baz = 'Equal';
} else {
    $baz = 'Less';
}
print $baz;
```

This combines the nested `if` into an `elseif`, improving readability.

Comment: I've added another example. When I did `elseif` it actually broke the script, which is why I'm here :)

Comment: I think the issue might be a problem with the variables. Try the revised version of the code.

Comment: Or, check out [switch statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). They might be an alternative that works for you.

Comment: I screwed up something when I originally did my conversion and it works with the `elseif`, so instead of deleting this I'm gonna give you the credit. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you. If you like, I can put the original code back up.

Comment: Do what you want. I shouldn't have even posted this bc it was a screw up on my end. Gonna leave it for your credit and maybe it'll help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if ($foo)
    $bar = true;
else
    if ($bar)
    $baz = true;
else
    $barbaz = true;
```

can be rewritten as (i.e. is equivalent to):

```
if ($foo) {
    $bar = true;
} else if ($bar) {
    $baz = true;
} else {
    $barbaz = true;
}
```

This code:

```
if ($foo)
    $bar = true;
else
    if ($bar)
    $baz = true;
else
    if ($barbaz)
    $something = true;
else
    $barbaz = true;
```

can be rewritten as (i.e. is equivalent to):

```
if ($foo) {
    $bar = true;
} else if ($bar) {
    $baz = true;
} else if ($barbaz) {
    $something = true;
} else {
    $barbaz = true;
}
```